# Existence of non measurable set and ZF theory?

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Does statement: 'Existence of non measurable set' consistent with ZF theory. or if I throw Axiom of choice from ZFC theory. Can I prove or disprove existence of a countably additive measure function on all subsets of R which is translation invariant and in which measure of interval is equal to length of interval.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. It most certainly does not.

This would mean that the fact there are non-measurable sets is equivalent to the axiom of choice. This cannot possibly be true. Measures live on $\Bbb R$. That's an extremely localized set. The axiom of choice affects the entire universe of sets.

Not to mention that the existence of non-measurable sets can be proved (independently) from $\sf DC+\aleph_1\leq2^{\aleph_0}$, $\sf BPI$, The axiom of choice for family of pairs, Banach-Tarski paradox, existence of free ultrafilters on $\omega$, Hahn-Banach theorem, and more and more. You can find some nice diagrams in Herrlich's book The Axiom of Choice.

Beyond that lies another point. While Solovay proved that it is consistent that every set is Lebesgue measurable, this proof requires the existence of an inaccessible cardinal, and as Shelah showed later on, this requirement is really needed (we can remove it, but then we have to give up sigma additivity).

---

1. *Robert M. Solovay*, [**A model of set-theory in which every set of reals is Lebesgue measurable**](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=265151), *Ann. of Math. (2)* **92** (1970), 1--56.
2. *Saharon Shelah*, [**Can you take Solovay’s inaccessible away?**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02760522), *Israel J. Math.* **48** (1984), no. 1, 1--47.
3. *Horst Herrlich*, **The Axiom of Choice**, *Springer Lecture Notes in Mathematics* **1876** (2006).

Comment: Can you please help me finding second paper. i am unable to find it.

Comment: What do you mean? There's a link in the reference.

Comment: Ya but I am unable to find soft copy of this. Would I have to buy this paper to read it?

Comment: Try accessing the paper through the university computers.

Comment: I am using university computer. Can you please just send me link if you are able to find it so that I can also try accessing it?

Comment: Alright. But I should warn you that this paper is very hard to read. Shelah is not famous for being a great writer, just a great mathematician. I think there are papers by other people which do a better job proving this.

Comment: Ok I want to study on this topic. I first want to have a look at paper(as you mentioned it). Then I'll search about it more and find papers which will be easy to study.

Comment: If you want to study this topic, reading Shelah's paper (this particular one) is a long long long way down the road. First you need to be comfortable with topology, axiomatic set theory, forcing, models of set theory, some infinitary combinatorics, and so on and so forth. Studying the basics is something you should do from books, like Jech, Kanamori, Kunen, Halbeisen, and later on Shelha's book. I don't think that learning the basics from papers is a wise thing to do.

Comment: This is what I am doing these days. Building concepts to be able to study these papers. And this question was which comes in mind. So i just want to collect first information to study about it.(and your answer give me much more information I have not even expected)

Comment: Well, I'd postpone Shelah's paper until much later.

Comment: Ok I'll then talk to you about this paper after firming my concepts in topics required to study it.